# Not able to execute pandas read_excel function twice, when referring the object from AWS S3 bucket

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3

Trying to read multiple worksheets from the same excel file stored in the S3 bucket.

The code works fine for the first time, but while trying to execute the read_excel function for the second time to read another worksheet from the same excel file, getting an error. Though the "obj" object remains constant, the read_excel function doesn't work.

```
obj = S3_Client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=str(XLSX_Keys.iloc[0,0]))
File1 = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()) , sheet_name = "Sheet1",dtype=str, header= 4)
File2 = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()) , sheet_name = "Sheet2",dtype=str, header= 4)
```

**ValueError: File is not a recognized excel file**

For now, re-executing the get_object function one more time before executing the read_excel function for reading the second sheet from the same excel file.

like this

```
obj = S3_Client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=str(XLSX_Keys.iloc[0,0]))
File1 = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()) , sheet_name = "Sheet1",dtype=str, header= 4)
obj = S3_Client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=str(XLSX_Keys.iloc[0,0]))
File2 = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()) , sheet_name = "Sheet2",dtype=str, header= 4)
obj = S3_Client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=str(XLSX_Keys.iloc[0,0]))
File3 = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()) , sheet_name = "Sheet3",dtype=str, header= 4)
```

This is of course very redundant coding, so looking for some advice. Thanks!!

Comment: Guess `.read()` can be called only once ? You'd better save `obj['Body'].read()` in a variale and reuse it instead

Comment: Wow, that worked. Thank you Azro!!! Looks like after the first call there is nothing left in the file to be read (reason for the error "ValueError: File is not a recognized excel file" ). Needed to execute .read() again to open the file one more time and read the contents again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save what you `read` to be reused

```
obj = S3_Client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=str(XLSX_Keys.iloc[0, 0]))
content = obj['Body'].read()

File1 = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(content), sheet_name="Sheet1", dtype=str, header=4)
File2 = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(content), sheet_name="Sheet2", dtype=str, header=4)
```